# $\nu(A)=\int \mathcal{X}_{A}f(x)d\mu$ measure associated functional $l_{\nu}(g)=\int g(x)f(x)d\mu.$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a positive Baire measure, $f\in L^1(X,d\mu)$ with $X$ compact hausdorff and $f\geq 0$.
For any Baire set $A$, define $\nu(A)=\int \mathcal{X}_{A}f(x)d\mu$.
Show that $\nu$ is the one measure associated to the functional on $C(X)$,

$l_{\nu}(g)=\int g(x)f(x)d\mu.$

Hello! In general, what are the steps to demonstrate that a measure comes from a functional one?

Comment: There is probably a theorem that gives you uniqueness of measures if the two measures coincide in a set of functions. And that would do it.

Comment: You are supposed to show that $l_{\nu} g=\int g d\nu$ for all $g \in C(X)$. In other words you have to show that $\int g(x)f(x)d\mu(x)=\int g(x)d\nu(x)$.